# MongoDB Charts Aggregation: filter string categories where one is included in another

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here are some documents of my collection:

```
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047df24",
  "cid": "10000",
  "stage": "stage1"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047df25",
  "cid": "10001",
  "stage": "stage1"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047df26",
  "cid": "10002",
  "stage": "stage1"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047re35",
  "cid": "10000",
  "stage": "stage2"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047re78",
  "cid": "10002",
  "stage": "stage2"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047x567",
  "cid": "10000",
  "stage": "stage3"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047xas6",
  "cid": "10001",
  "stage": "stage3"
}
{
  "_id":"630c7a2e5ecd8b099047qwe2",
  "cid": "10002",
  "stage": "stage3"
}
```

You could see that for these 3 `cid`s, 2 of them have gone to `stage2` and then `stage3`, while 1 directly jumped from `stage1` to `stage3`.

Now I want to create a donut chart in the `MongoDB Charts`. The `label` should be `has_stage2` and `no_stage2`, meaning how it reached `stage3`. And the `arc` is the distinct count of the `cid`s, namely `2` and `1` (in `stage3` but not in `stage2`).

```
   label               arc: distinct(cid)
0  has_stage2          2
1  no_stage2           1
```

The following is the aggregation pipeline of `has_stage2` and `has_stage3`. How do I exclude `stage2` from `has_stage3` in order to get `no_stage2`?

```
[
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "cid":{
            "$convert":{
               "input":"$cid",
               "to":"string",
               "onError":null
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "stage":{
            "$in":["stage2", "stage3"]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "stage":{
            "$switch":{
               "branches":[
                  {
                     "case":{
                        "$in":[
                           {
                              "$toString":"$stage"
                           },
                           [
                              {
                                 "$literal":"stage2"
                              }
                           ]
                        ]
                     },
                     "then":"has_stage2"
                  },
                  {
                     "case":{
                        "$in":[
                           {
                              "$toString":"$stage"
                           },
                           [
                              {
                                 "$literal":"stage3"
                              }
                           ]
                        ]
                     },
                     "then":"has_stage3"
                  }
               ],
               "default":"Other values"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "__alias_0":"$stage"
         },
         "__alias_1":{
            "$addToSet":"$cid"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "_id":0,
         "__alias_0":"$_id.__alias_0",
         "__alias_1":{
            "$size":"$__alias_1"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "value":"$__alias_1",
         "label":"$__alias_0",
         "_id":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "__agg_sum":{
            "$sum":[
               "$value"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "__agg_sum":-1
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "__agg_sum":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$limit":5000
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `$group`ing approach. In order to know if a `cid` "skipped" stage 2 you must group by `cid` first.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "cid": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$cid",
          "to": "string",
          "onError": null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "stage": {
        "$in": [
          "stage2",
          "stage3"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$cid",
      stages: {
        "$addToSet": "$stage"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      noStage2: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              [
                "stage3"
              ],
              "$stages"
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      hasStage2: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "stage2",
                "$stages"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      hasStage3: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: [
                "stage3",
                "$stages"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      noStage2: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                [
                  "stage3"
                ],
                "$stages"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWKz7iKSrjk)